# PostScript Driver for DVI Files has stopped working

Tags: floats, dvi, postscript

[image]

How do i enable the PostScript Driver for DVI Files to work properly.I am not able to insert pictures in my latex document in PCTEX. How can i fix this problem?

Comment: that can be anything! Without an example file difficult to say. Maybe a not supported type of an image.